# Angular 2 wrapper project

Tags: angular, npm, angular-ui-router, wrapper, router

I have to develop an angular 2 application which is the wrapper of other angular 2 applications.

Lets say the main Module of project is called MainModule
Other 3rd party modules which are deployed in npm are AppModule1, AppModule2,...
I can install them into my main project with 'npm i appmodule1' etc..

Here is my code:

```
import {AppModule1} from 'ThirdPartyLibrary/AppModule1';
import {AppModule2} from 'ThirdPartyLibrary/AppModule2';
import {AppModule3} from 'ThirdPartyLibrary/AppModule3';
```

(import rest of the modules too)
..(lets say I made this dynamic)

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    AppModule1,AppModule2,..(lets say I made this dynamic)
],
declarations: [
    MainComponent
],
schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
providers: [
    AnyMainModuleService,
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
],
bootstrap: [ MainComponent ]
```

})
export class MainModule { }

AppModule1,2,3.. has its RouterModule.forChild(routes) in the imports array. I also tried using RouterModule.forRoot(routes).

**Router configuration:**

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'AppComponent1' },
{ path: 'appcomponent1', component: AppComponent1 },
{ path: 'appcomponent2', component: AppComponent2 },
{ path: 'appcomponent3', component: AppComponent3 },
{ path: 'appcomponent4', component: AppComponent4, children: childRoutesOfAppModule4enter code here },
```

**Router config inside AppModule4**

```
 export const routes: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home'},
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent}
    ];
```

The question is The router configuration of AppModule4 which is supposed to be child route of main component is over-riding the main router.

as soon as I enter localhost I got to see the AppComponent1 but I get HomeComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ path: 'appcomponent4', component: AppComponent4, loadChildren: () => AppModule4}
```

use this to import the router module and inside the AppModule4 install routes as RouterModule.forChild(routes)